# Selecting an ancestor up the hierarchy using JSON.Net / JSONPath

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

Using JSON.Net / JSONPath, is there a way to go up the JSON object hierarchy, other than calling `JToken.Parent` multiple times?

For example, for the following JSON:

```
{
  "grandparent" : {
    "parent" : {
      "child" : {
        "property" : "value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Selecting the contents of "child" is easy enough:

```
var theChild = theJson.SelectToken("$.grandparent.parent.child");
```

But if I now want to select the contents of "grandparent" from "child", the only way I can figure out to do it is by calling:

```
var theGrandparent = theChild.Parent.Parent.Parent;
```

Which seems a bit clumsy. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no provision in JSONPath for selecting a parent node from a child.  See http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath.  Therefore you will need to use the `.Parent` property on the `JToken` like you are already doing.